# Some records not being indexed by sunspot/solr

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

Why would some records not get indexed by sunspot/solr? I have tried reindexing and still the same results.

For instance if I search for "game of thrones"

I will get records like:

```
Game of Thrones Journal - Stark Notebook

Game of Thrones House Stark Phone Case

Game of Thrones Inspired Wooden Box
```

But I noticed that this product that is in the db was not coming up in searches:

```
Game of Thrones Life Size Replica Iron Throne Chair
```

These are the name columns from the db and there are definitely set to searchable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that that one of the searchable columns for that record was nil.